# Crontab in Python creates cron job, but doesn't run script

Tags: python, cron

Not sure what I'm doing wrong whether it's the code, the directory, or something else. Please help!

```
from crontab import CronTab

my_cron = CronTab(user='bgoldberg')
job = my_cron.new(command='python /Users/bgoldberg/PythonScripts/FunStuff/writeDate.py')
job.minute.every(1)
my_cron.write()
```

And here's the writeDate.py script:

```
import datetime

with open('dateInfo.txt','a') as outFile:
    outFile.write('\n' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

The writeDate.py script just writes the current timestamp to a txt file and it works fine when run separately. When I run python scheduleCron.py, it runs without error but it seems that it's not running the writeDate.py script because no txt file is created. When I enter crontab -l it correctly shows the job that was created: ***** python /Users/bgoldberg/PythonScripts/FunStuff/writeDate.py

Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Are somehow activating the environment you're using before the script is run in cron?

Comment: What directory are you checking for the text file?  Does `writeDate.py` create the text file in the current directory, or some specific directory?

Comment: How long are you waiting before checking for the text file?  i.e. if you create a new cron job at ten seconds past the minute, it won't run for another 50 seconds.

Comment: You should also show us the contents of `writeDate.py`.

Comment: Thanks! Now change `'dateinfo.txt` to an absolute path and see if anything changes. For example `with open('/Users/bgoldberg/dateinfo.txt', 'a') as outFile:` and see if it writes to your home directory.

Comment: Ok added writeDate.py contents. And it should create the txt file in the same directory and I'm positive it's not updating. @snapcrack I don't think I'm using an environment, just created a .py file in my user directory and running on command line.

Comment: @d_kennetz that worked! Changed to absolute path and now it's showing up. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cron "gotcha". Cron uses the command

`python /Users/bgoldberg/PythonScripts/FunStuff/writeDate.py`

which you expect to write to your current working directory, but cron will write to `/var/log/syslog` or some variation of this by default. It is trying to write to some place you don't have the permissions to (but it won't die), so you need to specifiy the absolute path of your output file.

changing your line in `writeDate.py` to write to an absolute path:

```
with open('/Users/bgoldberg/dateinfo.txt', 'a') as outFile:
```

will solve your problem.